# deadline_exceeded unable to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I have a ruby app with total 1,2gb and always failed to deploy and getting this,

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at xxx. Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
```

Checking latest line in logs :

```
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:e1b46f9ec9520fc3260447d54f2c967cdebedb06404dcbb21fcb9b45d3a14f41" failed: exit status 2
```

And weird thing, when in process of deploying and is running step#1 Started cloud_sql_proxy,it shows all assets being written,and everthing after that line is written in red color.

```
Step #1: Started cloud_sql_proxy.
Step #1: I, [2017-09-26T17:05:48.942032 #16]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/email/logo-2260f0cc07e32ae067e1a6be7566a2b8.png
```

meanwhile, i tried to deploy with another app that have same settings & cloud_sql_instances with 1,2mb and it works smoothly. In process of deploying, the logs after cloud_sql_proxy become like this

```
Step #1: Started cloud_sql_proxy.
Step #1:  ---> [code]
Step #1: Removing intermediate container [code]
```

I dont know what is causing this, please help !